# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[1,\infty)$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $f(n)<1/n$ then is $x\in\mathbb{R},x>1\implies f(x)<1/x$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[1,\infty)$. If for every natural number $n$ we have $f(n)<1/n$ then can we say that for every real number $x$ such that $x>1$ we have $f(x)<1/x$?

After coming up with this question I looked for examples. The only examples I can find are functions of the "form" of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}.$$ Since I can't find any counterexamples, I assume the answer is affirmative. I don't know how to proceed, although I think the intermediate value theorem can help here.

Comment: Why should that conclusion hold? If $f$ is “small” at the integers then it can still take arbitrary values at non-integer arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(n)=0<\frac1n$. Besides, $f$ is continuous.

However, $f\left(\frac52\right)=1$ and $1>\frac25$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{gather}
f(n)<\dfrac 1n \ \forall \ n \in N \\\\
\text{We can write x = [x] + {x}}\\
\therefore f(x) = \frac{1}{[x]+\{x\}}\\
\text{since} \ \{x\} > 0 \ \forall \ x\\
\therefore \frac{1}{[x]} > \frac{1}{[x]+\{x\}};\ x>0 \ \text{and}\ \ \frac{1}{[x]} < \frac{1}{[x]+\{x\}};\ x<0 \ 
\\
\text{hence for} \ x>1 \ \text{we cannot conclude that} \ f(x) <\dfrac 1n
\end{gather}

Comment: This seems like the answer given when 1 marks question comes for 5 marks XD just realised.